# bootstrap alert closing inconsistently with timeout

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, bootstrap-4, smarty3

This is a very difficult problem to explain and demo, basically I am using a mixture of PHP, Smarty, Ajax and Bootstrap.

I have a smarty template with an Ajax form in it (this works), a PHP backend which adds the form details into a database (this also works), on success or failure an alert is shown, this alert is from the Bootstrap CSS, it is written to the page as follows.

```
$('form').append('<div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible" role="alert">' + data.message + '<a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a></div>');
```

The alert does display in the page, and the alert does close! I did have a problem that the alert wouldn't close after the form had been submitted once, this was solved with the following code, but this code introduced a new problem in that the alert doesn't close with any consistency, I would like the alert to display for 5 seconds before it closes, it doesn't always do this it sometimes closes instantly or atleast under a second of it being displayed.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('form').submit(function(event) {

        // snip

        var alertTimer1 = window.setInterval(function() {
            if (typeof alertTimer2 === 'undefined') {
                var alertTimer2 = window.setTimeout(function() {
                    $('#alert').find('.alert').fadeTo(1000, 0).slideUp(1000, function() {
                        $(this).remove();

                        window.clearInterval(alertTimer1);
                        window.clearTimeout(alertTimer2);
                    });
                }, 5000);
            }
        }, 100);
    }
}
```

Does anyone have a solution for the problems of displaying an alert, closing that alert, closing subsequent alerts without the page being refreshed after being displayed for 5 seconds.

Comment: `if (typeof alertTimer2 === 'undefined') {`  will always be true.  `alertTimer2` is created only after that line, and every invocation of the callback given to the interval will create it's own `alertTimer2` at that point.

Comment: `$('#alert').find('.alert')` is finding all alert elements within the element with the alert id.  If multiple intervals are running due to multiple submits happening, the first will be able to close the alerts from the second submit.

Comment: @Taplar Oh! I wasn't aware of that, thank you for pointing that out to me.  I'm hoping that users won't be submitting records so fast that more than one alert will be in the page at a time.  Also only one div with the id of #alert will exist, but inside this there could be potentially multiple divs with the class of alert.